# In magento - same code for getting all categories running well with sorted in localhost but not in web server

Tags: magento

I have got all categories **sorted** as in admin in localhost but in web server its coming without **sorted**. I tried same code and order in both localhost and web server.
That is really a pain.Please help me!
Here is my code:

```
$categories = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$collection = $categories->getStoreCategories(false,true,false);
foreach($collection as $_category)
{
   //Do something
   echo $_category->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In helper:

```
 /**
 * Retrieve current store categories
 *
 * @param   boolean|string $sorted
 * @param   boolean $asCollection
 * @return  Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection|Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection|array
 */
public function getStoreCategories($sorted=false, $asCollection=false, $toLoad=true)
```

And your first parameter equals to false, means collection won't be sorted.

```
$collection = $categories->getStoreCategories(false,true,false);
```

Comment: But in localhost categories coming sorted. So why?

Comment: Well. Can't say for sure. Might be that you added categories in different orders in web site and localhost, thus it loads categories id based. Don't know for sure. Please try snippet provided.

Comment: I have tried with first parameter true, but it still not sorted.

Comment: I wrote this code: `$categories = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation; echo $categories->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top');` Is this a correct solution?

Comment: If you want your categories sorted - no, this snippet is for rendering menu. Uhm very strange that changing parameter didn't worked. Nevertheless you can try to load categories collection and setting order there.