# sort collection of category by name

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have custom links in menu that shows categories in drop-down.
For that I made a file in `catalog/navigation->mainmenu.phtml`
(a custom file)
Now, I want to show categories after sorting it by name. please help me how can I sort collection of categories by name. I already set order of category in admin. But in front-end it show unsorted.
Code is:-

```
<?php $defaultcategory= Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();?>
  <?php $mainchildren = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($defaultcategory);?>
   <ul>
              <?php foreach ($mainchildren as $subcategory) : ?> <?php // 2 level ?>
                <?php if($subcategory->getIsActive()):?>
                 <li id="show_subcat" class="<?php if($i==1): echo 'first'; endif; ?>" >
                      <?php  $childid=$subcategory->getId();?> 
                     <?php $subchild = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($childid);?>
                      <?php foreach ($subchild as $subchildcategory) : ?> 
                         <?php $path=$subchildcategory->getRequestPath()?>
                         <?php break;?>
                     <?php endforeach ?>
                     <a  href="<?php echo  $this->getUrl().$path; ?>">
                       <?php echo $name= $subcategory->getName().$subcategory->getEnable() ?>
                     </a>
                 </li>
                 <?php endif;?>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$categories = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$collection = $categories->getStoreCategories(false,true,false);
foreach($collection as $_category)
 {
    //Do something
    echo $_category->getName();
  }
```

use this code to get collection and follow this link for more detail[In magento - same code for getting all categories running well with sorted in localhost but not in web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307117/in-magento-same-code-for-getting-all-categories-running-well-with-sorted-in-lo)

Comment: some changes are:-  $collection = $categories->getStoreCategories(true,true,false);. It will fetch all categories, so put condition as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($defaultcategory)
                                             ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```

or :

```
children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($defaultcategory)
                                             ->setOrder('name','ASC);
```

Comment: What about replace "Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($defaultcategory)" by "$defaultcategory->getChildrenCategories()" ?

Comment: I think it show error as code is not written in topmenu.phtml. So it can't access methods